# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at <anonymous>:1:6 | while trying to parse

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I am getting this error while trying to parse some strings.
The error is occurring after I tried to fix another error where I was parsing an already parsed string.
Getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at :1:6

```
if (typeof localStorage.plannerTable != 'object' && localStorage.plannerTable !== undefined) {
    console.log('parsing')
    var parsedPlannerTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.plannerTable)
} else {
    parsedPlannerTable = localStorage.plannerTable
}
function checkEdits() {
    if (localStorage.plannerTable !== undefined && localStorage.plannerTable !== null) {
        let plannerTableDict = parsedPlannerTable
        // console.log('checkEdits planerTableDict', plannerTableDict)
        // console.log("plannerTable exists", plannerTableDict)
        // console.log('plannerTableDict is a ', typeof plannerTableDict)
        for (id in plannerTableDict) {
             // console.log(id, plannerTableDict[id])
             if (plannerTableDict[id] !== null && plannerTableDict[id] !== '') {
                 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = plannerTableDict[id]
             }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("plannerTable does not exist.")
    }
}
function saveEdits() {
    let tempPlannerDict = {}
    for (r=1; r<10; r++) {
        for (c=1; c<8; c++) {
            try {
                tempPlannerDict['iR' + r + 'C' + c] = document.getElementById('iR' + r + 'C' + c).innerHTML
            } catch (error) {
                // console.log('error:', error)
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Done", tempPlannerDict)
    localStorage.plannerTable = JSON.stringify(tempPlannerDict)
}
function clearPlanner(){
    localStorage.removeItem('plannerTable')
    location.reload()
}
function clearWork(){
    let tempPlannerDict = parsedPlannerTable
    // console.log('tempPlannerDict',tempPlannerDict)
    for (element in tempPlannerDict) {
        console.log(element.substring(2,3), element.substring(4), element)
        if (element.substring(2,3) != 1 && element.substring(4) == 1) {
            console.log('clearing item')
            tempPlannerDict[element] = ''
        }
    }
    console.log('tempPlannerDict', tempPlannerDict)
    localStorage.plannerTable = JSON.stringify(tempPlannerDict)
    // console.log(tempPlannerDict)
    // location.reload()
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who decides to help me.

Comment: "plannerTEST.html:164 string undefined" is my console log

Comment: for (id in plannerTableDict) {
             // console.log(id, plannerTableDict[id])
             if (plannerTableDict[id] !== null && plannerTableDict[id] !== '') {
                 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = plannerTableDict[id]
             }
        }
    } else {
  console.log("plannerTable does not exist.")
 }

Comment: how would I go about doing that?